# ошибки SSL протокола

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ssl

когда использую самый обыкновенный `requests.get()` питон выдает ошибки ssl сертификата

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 603, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 344, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 843, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 370, in connect
>       ssl_context=context)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py",
>   line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
>       return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 412, in wrap_socket
>       session=session   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 853, in _create
>       self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 1117, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 449, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 641, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
>   line 399, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='e.mail.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\test1.py", line 3, in 
>       requests.get("https://e.mail.ru")   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
>   line 75, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
>   line 60, in request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 514, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='e.mail.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))

Попробовал воспользоваться пипом, после чего вылетела вот такая ошибка

> C:\Users\ADMIN>cd AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\scripts
>
> C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip
>   install ssl Collecting ssl   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
>   read=None, redirect=None, status=None))  after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
>   CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local
>   issuer certif icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/ssl/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
>   after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,
>   '[SSL: CERTIFI CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable
>   to get local issuer certif icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/ssl/
>   Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None))  after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
>   CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local
>   issuer certif icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/ssl/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
>   after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,
>   '[SSL: CERTIFI CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable
>   to get local issuer certif icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/ssl/
>   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None))  after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFI
>   CATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local
>   issuer certif icate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/ssl/   Could not fetch
>   URL https://pypi.org/simple/ssl/: There was a problem confirmi ng the
>   ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
>   retr ies exceeded with url: /simple/ssl/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError (1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get l
>   ocal issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping   Could not find
>   a version that satisfies the requirement ssl (from versions: ) No
>   matching distribution found for ssl You are using pip version 19.0.3,
>   however version 19.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via
>   the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

так же пробовал добавить сайты в исключения командой

> pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host
>   files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools

однако это тоже не принесло никаких результатов, ошибка все та же

Искал решение проблемы, но все они для макоси, в то время как у меня это все происходит на винде. Питон версии 3.7.3

Comment: Для начала такой вопрос: у Вас установлена `SSL` для Python? Делали что-то типа `pip install ssl`?

Comment: До вашего сообщения не пробовал, добавил текст выше.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `pip install pyopenssl`

Comment: не, cmd выдает все ту же ошибку

Answer (score 6):

На вашем ПК проблема с цепочкой корневых сертификатов. В качестве временного костыля, можете убрать проверку валидности сертификата, добавив в код:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

или в самом реквесте указать verify = False:

`requests.get(url, verify=False)`

Если устранять проблему правильно, то нужно либо обновить сертификаты, путь до их располжения можно узнать через

```
import ssl
print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)
```

либо использовать серты, которые идут в составе либ, например certifi.